# What is a local operator?

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, linear-algebra

I have a sort of basic question. I think an operator that acts on $n$-partite states is defined (up to permutation of parties) to be local if it can be written as

$$A  = A_1 \otimes_{i=2}^n \mathbb{I}_i $$

where the subscript $i$ denotes the party on which an operator acts. This definition ensures that $A$ is acting only on one party (here we are assuming that each party is spatially separated from the rest). So far so good. The problem comes when I consider concatenation of operators. Consider for instance a 3-qubit system, and consider the local operators

$$\mathcal{O}_1 = Z_1 \otimes \mathbb{I}_2 \otimes \mathbb{I}_3 \, , \quad \mathcal{O}_2 = \mathbb{I}_1 \otimes Z_2 \otimes \mathbb{I}_3 \, , \quad \mathcal{O}_3 = \mathbb{I}_1 \otimes \mathbb{I}_2 \otimes Z_3  \, ,  $$

i.e. $\mathcal{O}_i$ applies the $Z$ gate to party $i$ and does nothing to the rest. If Alice performs $\mathcal{O}_1$, then Bob performs  $\mathcal{O}_2$  and then Charlie performs $\mathcal{O}_3$, which I understand is a protocol within the LOCC rules (actually no communication is needed at all) then the resulting gate is

$$ \mathcal{O}_3 \mathcal{O}_2 \mathcal{O}_1 = Z_1 \otimes Z_2 \otimes Z_3 \, ,$$

which I would say is a non-local operator. How is it that a succession of local operators gives rise to a non local operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the context in which you're using the operators. You're talking about multiplying them, so I guess you're thinking of, for example, unitaries (and other circuit model elements). In this case, not only are terms $A\otimes I$ local operators, but $A\otimes B$ is also a local operator. For example, on a quantum circuit, two Hadamard gates applied on neighbouring qubits are described as $H\otimes H$.

It is only when you take sums of local operators that you might create a non-local operator. For example, controlled-not is written as $I\otimes I+(I-Z)\otimes(X-I)/4$, and cannot be written in the form $A\otimes B$, corresponding with the fact that it's entangling. Given that this is the setting I believe you're talking about, **everything in your question is considered a local operator**.

---

The other context in which this might arrise is a Hamiltonian. If you have a Hamiltonian that is of the form $H=A\otimes I$, that Hamiltonian is local. However, a Hamiltonian $H=A\otimes B$ is not local. There is no contradiction here because you do not combine local Hamiltonians by product, but by adding them together, so there is no expectation that $A\otimes B$ should be local. Ultimately, what you're really thinking about is the resultant evolution, $e^{-iHt}$. There, you can see that $H=A\otimes B$ produces unitaries that are non-local in the previous sense, while if I added local operators, $H=A\otimes I+I\otimes B$, that produces local operators $e^{-iAt}\otimes e^{-iBt}$ in the same sense as before.

Answer (score 3):

There are two inequivalent definitions of "local operator" used in quantum information theory.

The first definition is used in the context of communication over a classical channel (e.g. LOCC). In this context, you have a *fixed* partition of the complete Hilbert space into a tensor product of $k$ different subsystems, and the subsystems are assumed to be so far apart that no entangling operator can ever act on both of them. In this context, a "local operator" is defined to be an operator that can be expressed as a tensor product of operators that only act on an individual subsystem, i.e. $\bigotimes_{i=1}^k A_i$, where the operator $A_i$ acts on the $i$th subsystem. Under this definition, the product of local operators is always a local operator, because by definition $\left (\bigotimes_{i=1}^k A_i \right) \left( \bigotimes_{i=1}^k B_i \right) = \bigotimes_{i=1}^k (A_i B_i)$.

The second definition is primarily used in the context of many-body quantum physics, e.g. topological quantum computing. Here, a local operator isn't defined to act nontrivially on only one qubit, but instead on a fixed number of qubits (generally up to four in practice) that does not depend on the total number of qubits in the circuit. So for example a single operator that acts on all the qubits, or a fixed fraction of the qubits, would not count as local. The idea is that as the number of qubits gets large, the operator acts on a negligible small fraction of the total.

When thinking about hardware implementations of a quantum computer, there's sometimes also a natural sense in which some qubits are "next to" each other. In hardware implementations, it's usually easier to engineer multi-qubit gates that act on qubits that are physically close together. In this case, "local" can refer to gates that only act on qubits that are a maximum physical distance away (which will depend on the geometry in which they're laid out). Under this second definition, the product of local operators will in general be non-local if they act on qubits that are sufficiently far apart.

Comment: OK, let's say I have three qubits far apart from each other. Then I think my three operators above are local operators, while their product is not. What does this mean?

Comment: @MBolin Yes, I think that would be the standard usage if it's clear from context that the physical separation is important. It depends on the context in which the term is being used.

Comment: I think you are not answering my question. I am saying that I have the impression that the product of three local operators is not a local operators, since it implies correlations among the separated parties.

Comment: @MBolin Yes, that's correct. Sorry, but I'm not sure exactly what your question is. What do you mean by "What does this mean?"?

Comment: Is it correct? The product of three local operators (the concatenated application of three local gates) may not be local? I have slightly modified my question in order to make it clearer.

Comment: @MBolin I have now answered your question three times in a row. I will answer it one final time: **Yes, it is correct that the product of local operators can fail to be a local operator.** I don't know what you mean by "What does this mean?". It's just a straightforward mathematical fact that follows directly from the definition. I don't see why this fact is surprising, and you have not provided any reason why you would suspect otherwise.

Comment: @MBolin Respectly, I will no longer respond to yet another repetition of the same question unless you clarify what part of your question is not addressed by your own question and my answer.

Comment: what definition of "local operation" are you going by? When discussing entanglement "local operation" usually means non-entangling operations, that is, things of the form $\otimes_k A_k$ with $A_k$ acting on the $k$-th party. With this definition, the product of local operations remains a local operation

Comment: @glS There are two inequivalent definitions of "local operator" used in quantum information theory, both of which are pretty common. The definition that I was going by was, well, exactly the definition that I provided in my answer. But your definition is common as well, and rereading the OP I realized that that was probably the sense that the OP had in mind, so I revised my answer to explain both.